# Setting to cause a connection to never lock?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

Is there a setting (connection string or other) that makes all queries issued via a specific connection to never lock the tables?

I'm considering having a debug read only mode for my app, that will connect to production for debugging/data analysis purposes. I'm not sure this is a great idea, and want to protect myself as much as possible if I do it.

(If you question whether I should do it or not, please do so in a comment - the question is about the existance of such a setting, not why I should or shouldn't use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED` might do the trick. Look at isolation level docs in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://forums.developer.mindtouch.com/showthread.php?1044-giving-a-mysql-user-read-only-privileges (untested), just grant your debug user select privileges only and that should solve your problem.

Comment: It has read-only privilages, I don't think that means it doesn't lock tables. E.g if you select * from a table with 1,000,000 records, and while you're reading the results another thread tries to modify one of the records - I believe by default the other thread would be locked until you read all the records.